# Tree menus in JavaScript and css/html

Tags: javascript, html, css, treeview

I'm using a tree menu with JavaScript.  I'd like for the category link in the menu to remain open after I click the link and load the linked page.
I also want improve the code because when I load a page or refresh it, I can see all categories open and immediately close and I don't want to see this.

css menu:

```
/*css del menu*/
div#nav{width:230px;background: #00005A;font: 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif}
div#nav h3{font-size: 100%;margin: 0;padding: 4px 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid #FFF;color: #000;background-color: #7BA5E7}
div#nav ul,div#nav li{margin: 0;padding: 0;list-style-type: none}
div#nav a{display: block;padding-left: 15px;height: 18px;line-height: 18px;
    border-top: 1px solid #FFF;background-color: #BDBDBD;color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;font-weight: bold}
div#nav a:hover{color: #00005A;background-color: #0099FF}
div#nav ul ul a{color: #333; background-color: #AECDFF;font-weight: normal}
```

css for javascript

```
div.jsenable h3{cursor: pointer}
div.jsenable ul ul{display:none}
div#nav li.hide ul{display:none}
div#nav li.show ul{display:block}
div#nav li.show h3{background-color: #FF0}
```

file javascript

```
/*javascript per menu espandibile*/
window.onload=function(){
if(document.getElementsByTagName && document.getElementById){
    document.getElementById("nav").className="jsenable";
    BuildList();
    }
}

function BuildList(){
var hs=document.getElementById("nav").getElementsByTagName("h3");
for(var i=0;i<hs.length;i++){
    hs[i].onclick=function(){
        this.parentNode.className=(this.parentNode.className=="show") ? "hide" : "show";
        }
    }
}
```

I'll attach a .rar. I'm testing in local and with a snippet it doesn't work 
https://www.mediafire.com/?xnzykrm8x8r51p1

and this should be the result:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjqkh.png

p.s: there's also a problem with height. If you open all categories, the menu will overflow from the column and I don't know why.

```js
/*javascript per menu espandibile*/
window.onload=function(){
if(document.getElementsByTagName && document.getElementById){
    document.getElementById("nav").className="jsenable";
    BuildList();
    }
}

function BuildList(){
var hs=document.getElementById("nav").getElementsByTagName("h3");
for(var i=0;i<hs.length;i++){
    hs[i].onclick=function(){
        this.parentNode.className=(this.parentNode.className=="show") ? "hide" : "show";
        }
    }
}
```

```css
html{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

body {
 color:#000;
 text-align:justify;
}

.wrap_all{
 width:1024px;
 margin:0px auto;
 padding:10px;
 border:1px solid #444444;
}

.banner{
 padding:10px;
 border:1px solid #444444;
}

.nav_main{
 padding:10px;
 border:1px solid #444444;
}

.nav_main ul li{
 display:inline-block;
}

.content{
 float:center;
 padding:10px;
 border:1px solid #444444;
}

.footer{
 clear: both;
 padding:10px;
 border:1px solid #444444;
}

.left{
 height:100%;
 padding:10px;
 border:1px solid #444444;
 float: left;
}

.center{
 height:100%;
 padding:10px;
 border:1px solid #444444;
}

.navig A:link,.navig A:active,.navig A:visited {
text-decoration:none;
display:block;
text-align:center;
background-color:#6A875B;
width:100%;
font-size:11px;
color:#000;
margin-bottom:2px;
padding-bottom:2px;
padding-top:2px;
font-family:Georgia;
}
/*css del menu*/
div#nav{width:230px;background: #00005A;font: 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif}
div#nav h3{font-size: 100%;margin: 0;padding: 4px 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid #FFF;color: #000;background-color: #7BA5E7}
div#nav ul,div#nav li{margin: 0;padding: 0;list-style-type: none}
div#nav a{display: block;padding-left: 15px;height: 18px;line-height: 18px;
    border-top: 1px solid #FFF;background-color: #BDBDBD;color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;font-weight: bold}
div#nav a:hover{color: #00005A;background-color: #0099FF}
div#nav ul ul a{color: #333; background-color: #AECDFF;font-weight: normal}
/*css essenziale se javascript è abilitato*/
div.jsenable h3{cursor: pointer}
div.jsenable ul ul{display:none}
div#nav li.hide ul{display:none}
div#nav li.show ul{display:block}
div#nav li.show h3{background-color: #FF0}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Full Metal Panic Italy</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="template/style.css">
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="config/jsmenu.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="config/menu.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="config/expand.js"></script>
 <style type="text/css">
      html{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

body {
 color:#000;
 text-align:justify;
}

.wrap_all{
 width:1024px;
 margin:0px auto;
 padding:10px;
 border:1px solid #444444;
}

.banner{
 padding:10px;
 border:1px solid #444444;
}

.nav_main{
 padding:10px;
 border:1px solid #444444;
}

.nav_main ul li{
 display:inline-block;
}

.content{
 float:center;
 padding:10px;
 border:1px solid #444444;
}

.footer{
 clear: both;
 padding:10px;
 border:1px solid #444444;
}

.left{
 height:100%;
 padding:10px;
 border:1px solid #444444;
 float: left;
}

.center{
 height:100%;
 padding:10px;
 border:1px solid #444444;
}

.navig A:link,.navig A:active,.navig A:visited {
text-decoration:none;
display:block;
text-align:center;
background-color:#6A875B;
width:100%;
font-size:11px;
color:#000;
margin-bottom:2px;
padding-bottom:2px;
padding-top:2px;
font-family:Georgia;
}
/*css del menu*/
div#nav{width:230px;background: #00005A;font: 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif}
div#nav h3{font-size: 100%;margin: 0;padding: 4px 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid #FFF;color: #000;background-color: #7BA5E7}
div#nav ul,div#nav li{margin: 0;padding: 0;list-style-type: none}
div#nav a{display: block;padding-left: 15px;height: 18px;line-height: 18px;
    border-top: 1px solid #FFF;background-color: #BDBDBD;color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;font-weight: bold}
div#nav a:hover{color: #00005A;background-color: #0099FF}
div#nav ul ul a{color: #333; background-color: #AECDFF;font-weight: normal}
/*css essenziale se javascript è abilitato*/
div.jsenable h3{cursor: pointer}
div.jsenable ul ul{display:none}
div#nav li.hide ul{display:none}
div#nav li.show ul{display:block}
div#nav li.show h3{background-color: #FF0}

  li {list-style:none;}
 </style>

</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrap_all">
   <div class="banner"><h3>Questo è il banner</h3></div>
   <div class="nav_main">
   <ul align="center">

 <li><a href="../index.php?page=home">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="../index.php?page=tutorial">Tutorial</a></li>
 <li><a href="../index.php?page=html">html</a></li>
 <li><a href="../index.php?page=contatti">Contatti</a></li>

</ul>
   </div>
   <div class="content">
       <div class="left"><div id="nav">
<ul> 
 <li><h3>Storia</h3>
  <ul>
   <?php
    isset($_GET["page"]) ? $page=$_GET["page"] : $page="home";
    $links=array(
     "fmp_trama" => "Full Metal Panic!",
     "fumoffu_trama" => "Full Metal Panic? Fumoffu",
     "fmptsr" => "Full Metal Panic! TSR",
     "riassunti" => "Riassunti Episodi",
     "manga" => "Manga",
     "listamanga" => "Lista Manga",
     "lnrecensione" => "Romanzo",
     "romanzi" => "Lista Romanzi",
     "sigma" => "Sigma",
     "overload" => "Overload",
     "comicmission" => "Comic Mission",
     "another" => "Another",
     "sdnefd" => "SDNED",
     "zero" => "Zero",
     "riassunti_manga" => "Riassunti Manga",
     "riassuntiromanzi" => "Riassunti Romanzi"
    );
    foreach($links as $href=>$text){
     if($page!=$links){
     echo '<a href="?page='.$href.'">'.$text.'</a>';
     }else{echo $text;}
    }
   ?>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li><h3>Spoiler</h3>
  <ul>
   <?php
    isset($_GET["page"]) ? $page=$_GET["page"] : $page="home";
    $links=array(
     "infanziasousuke" => "Infanzia di Sousuke",
     "infanziatessa" => "Infanzia di Tessa",
     "infanziakurz" => "Infanzia di Kurz",
     "lemon" => "Michel Lemon",
     "origini" => "Le Origini",
     "finemithril" => "Fine della Mirthril",
     "yamsuk11" => "Yamsuk 11"
    );
    foreach($links as $href=>$text){
     if($page!=$links){
     echo '<a href="?page='.$href.'">'.$text.'</a>';
     }else{echo $text;}
    }
   ?>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li><h3>Gallery</h3>
  <ul>
   <?php
    isset($_GET["page"]) ? $page=$_GET["page"] : $page="home";
    $links=array(
     "fanart" => "FanArt",
     "wallpapers" => "Wallpapers",
     "animated" => "Animated",
     "avatars" => "Avatar",
     "cosplay" => "Cosplay"
    );
    foreach($links as $href=>$text){
     if($page!=$links){
     echo '<a href="?page='.$href.'">'.$text.'</a>';
     }else{echo $text;}
    }
   ?>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li><h3>Interviste</h3>
  <ul>
   <?php
    isset($_GET["page"]) ? $page=$_GET["page"] : $page="home";
    $links=array(
     "perla" => "Perla Liberatori",
     "lapenna" => "Leslie La Penna",
     "intervistavalerio" => "Valerio Manenti | J-Pop"
     );
    foreach($links as $href=>$text){
     if($page!=$links){
     echo '<a href="?page='.$href.'">'.$text.'</a>';
     }else{echo $text;}
    }
   ?>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li><h3>Other</h3>
  <ul>
   <?php
    isset($_GET["page"]) ? $page=$_GET["page"] : $page="home";
    $links=array(
     "faq" => "F.A.Q. e Curiosità",
     "episodi" => "Titoli Episodi",
     "mithril" => "Mithril",
     "merida" => "Isola Merida",
     "terroristi" => "Terroristi",
     "personaggi" => "Personaggi",
     "whispered" => "Whispered",
     "bt" => "Black Tecnology",
     "mech" => "Arm Slave",
     "tdd" => "Tuatha De Danaan",
     "palladio" => "Palladio",
     "armi" => "Armi",
     "lambdadriver" => "Lambda Driver",
     "gatoh" => "Shouji Gatoh",
     "shikidouji" => "Shiki Douji",
     "doppiaggio_ita" => "Doppiaggio Italiano",
     "doppiaggio" => "Doppiaggio",
     "frasi" => "Frasi Celebri",
     "doms" => "D.O.M.S",
     "luoghi" => "Luoghi",
     "sicilia" => "Viaggio a Canicatti",
     "tateo" => "Retsu Tateo",
     "filmvsanime" => "Film Vs Anime"
     );
    foreach($links as $href=>$text){
     if($page!=$links){
     echo '<a href="?page='.$href.'">'.$text.'</a>';
     }else{echo $text;}
    }
   ?>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li><h3>Multimedia</h3>
  <ul>
   <?php
    isset($_GET["page"]) ? $page=$_GET["page"] : $page="home";
    $links=array(
     "soundtrack" => "Soundtrack",
     "testi" => "Lyric",
     "midi" => "Videosigle",
     "trailers" => "Trailers",
     "music_video" => "Music Video",
     "winamp" => "Skin Winamp",
     "nsliveaction" => "Nostro Live Action",
     "dvd_vhs" => "DVD/VHS",
     "shimokawa" => "Mikuni Shimokawa",
     "sahashi" => "Toshihiko Sahashi",
     "chrome" => "Tema Google Chrome",
     "firefoz" => "Tema Firefox",
     "app" => "App Smartphone"
     );
    foreach($links as $href=>$text){
     if($page!=$links){
     echo '<a href="?page='.$href.'">'.$text.'</a>';
     }else{echo $text;}
    }
   ?>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>    
    <div class="center">
     <?php include("$page.php") ?>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="footer"><p>Tutti i diritti sono riservati</p></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you create a snippet on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: I've added an archive with all files.

Comment: I think it's time to you start learning AngularJS :)

Comment: Done. But to work better, download the archive.